# Material for "sponge" wall paint

Tags: materials

I managed to import a SweetHome3D room into Blender and now try to get the walls look as if they were painted using "sponge technique" i.e. covered with "ingrain wallpaper", painted with a basic color and then again using a sponge and a second color.

Any idea where I could find an existing material or how to create one myself?
Images on the Net are usually not seamless and neither are ones that I could create with GIMP. Could Blender generate this effect procedurally?

Example:
[image: Example for sponge painted wall]

Edit: 
Screenshot of not working node setup
[image: Screenshot of not working node setup]

Edit:
[image: Final node setup]

Comment: Its hard to say if I can't see what you need, are there any example images you could provide?

Comment: I've added an example picture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one result you could achieve with noise and voronoi textures:

[image]

The concept is fairly simple, first create two base shaders.
 Here it is the two sets of diffuse/ glossy. One for the darker and lighter color of the paint. Then, just mix between them with a noise texture.

The scale of the noise texture will control how much variation there is between the two layers, and where the variation falls. The color ramp will control the intensity of the transition between the layers. Changing the *interpolation* to *ease* or *b-spline* might be interesting depending on your needs.

Then use voronoi (or some other texture with high scale) for bump to give the texture of the wall.

Here is the node setup for the example above:

[image]

<sup>*click to enlarge*</sup>

Comment: I tried to use the node setup from your image but somehow it does not work. It only gives solid brown.What am I missing? See second attached image.

Comment: You can tweak the color ramp going into the last mix shader (try holding shift to be more precise) for more control.  This will mix more or less of the top or bottom socket into it.

Comment: I wasn't aware that Blender does not generate a preview in Viewport-mode "Material" as it does for the image texture based materials. Only in rendering mode the noise pattern becomes visisble. I've added a screenshot of the values I've finanally used.